# RC noise figure calculation

Tags: noise, bandwidth, noise-spectral-density

[image]
I would ask for some help with noise figure calculation for circuit attached. It is front end of improvised differential probe that I would like to build. I am aware that simulators such as LTSpice can analyze noise. However, I would much more prefer to understand it.

Since all resistors have capacitor in parallel does it mean bandwidth used in noise formula [4*k*T*R*B] is based on RC?
Also, since all the noise sources create potential divider is there any special consideration, I should take adding them or is sum of square roots still valid?